# what is <class> in load_obj.AddComponent<Class>();?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to c# and cant figure out what this does

```
load_obj.AddComponent<Class1>();
                     ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Generics: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construct is called [Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) In this case it allows you to specify a type parameter of AddComponent method, which is Class1. Class1 is a class definition of MonoBehaviour which is going to be attached as instance to load_obj.

This is language construct which allows you to write classes and methods accepting any (generic) class to work with. Without this construct it would still be possible to work with unknown classes (at least in .NET), however the code would be much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure what you want but you can read that..

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html

Answer (score 0):

It is a [generic function](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GenericFunctions.html), so that it only accepts types that are or that inherit from that component (the generic parameter has to be a compile-time type).